# Precalculus - connect 2 towns

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, word-problem

A state highway department plans to construct a new road between towns $A$ and $B$.
Town $A$ lies on an abandoned road that runs east-west. Town $B$ is $20$ miles north of the point on that road that is $40$ miles east of $A$. The engineering division proposes that the road be constructed by restoring a section of the old road from $A$ up to a point $C$ and joining it to a new road that connects $C$ and $B$. If the cost of restoring the old road is \$200,000 per mile and the cost of the new road is \$400,000 per mile, determine the function describing the total cost. Estimate how much of the old road should be restored in order to minimize the department’s costs.

I'm having trouble with how to determine the function to describe the total cost. My thought process was to solve for the hypotenuse. I used $40-x$ as the base, and $20$ as the height, and came up with the $\sqrt{x^2-80x+2000}$. but then i get stuck as to what to do next – 
I don't know whether the cost $=200,000x+400,000\sqrt{x^2-80x+2000}$, or if there is a way to simplify. It's also confusing to me because I know when solving the hypotenuse it results in imaginary numbers. –

[image]

[image]

Comment: What difficulty are you having with this exercise?

Comment: Is this *really* a precalc problem?

Comment: Yes it is a precalc problem! I'm having trouble with how to determine the function to describe the total cost. My thought process was to solve for the hypotenuse. I used 40-x as the base, and 20 as the height, and came up with the sqrt(x^2-80x+2000). but then i get stuck as to what to do next

Comment: I don't know whether the cost=200,000x+400,000sqrt(x^2-80x+2000), or if there is a way to simplify. It's also confusing to me because I know when solving the hypotenuse it results in imaginary numbers.

Comment: The image! I'm sorry I didn't realize! I wil try to edit the post

Comment: Am I on the right track in solving for the hypotenuse and then adding AC to CB? Does the function properly descrive total cost?

Comment: your cost looks good. I'm not sure where you are getting imaginary numbers.

Comment: When trying to simplify sqrt{x^2-80x+2000} I came up with imaginary numbers. To be honest I've been working on this equation for so long, I know I got complex roots of x=40-20i.

Comment: After graphing the cost function, how do I estimate how much of the old road should be restored to minimize cost?

Comment: I use http://www.wolframalpha.com/ to graph because I currently don't have a graphing calculator. When I input the cost function, two graphs are supplied: one with x from -156541 to 156541, and the second with x from -1.1x10^6 to 1.1x10^6.

Comment: I don't know how to add an image of the graph to show.

Comment: Well, you don't want x to go outside 0 to 40 obviously. That would be meaningless.

Comment: I added the image of the graph at the botton of the post.

Comment: I know x<40, but how do I determine x to minimize total cost?

Comment: Only by graphing, really, unless you use differentiation. ie. calculus.

Comment: In Alpha you can say plot blah from a to b to get the range you want.  It looks like when you say "solve the hypotenuse" you are setting the square root to zero.  You are trying to find the $x$ that minimizes the cost, which does not involve setting the square root to zero.

Comment: On www.wolframalpha.com it calculates min{y = 200000 x+400000 sqrt(x^2-80 x+2000)} = 4000000 (2+sqrt(3)) at x = 40-20/sqrt(3). But I don't understand how this was calculated. Can you explain how the minimum is determined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your thought is correct, as is your expression for the cost of the road.  Now in a calculus class you would be expected to take the derivative of the cost with respect to $x$, set it to zero, and solve the resulting equation.  As you tagged it precalculus people are confused because we assume you don't know how to take the derivative.  Do you?  Alternately you could ask Alpha to plot over a much smaller range and find the minimum that way.  I would start plotting from $0$ to $40$, see where the minimum seems to be, and zoom in.

Comment: No, I don't know how to take the derivative. I am only 3 weeks into my precalculus class, and in said class we get a weekly assignment. This is one of the assignments. When I approached my professor with questions I was told to think about the problem more because he did not want to give me the answer.

Comment: In Alpha, I input the function and then "plot from 0-40" but the same graph was given. Is there a specific way for me to input the request?

Comment: Then I think graphing over a smaller range is the answer.  I have had success with plot f(x) from 0 to 40 in Alpha.

Comment: I'm still having difficulty on Alpha..The same graph keeps getting provided, despite trying to limit the range. I input "plot f(x)=200000x+400,000sqrt(x2−80x+2000) from 0-40" and have also tried "from origin". Is there any other way to define it?

Comment: When I put it into [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+200000*x%2B400000*sqrt%28x%5E2-80*x%2B2000%29+from+0+to+40) I got just what you would want. Then changing the range to 25 to 30 gets closer.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to click on the link to view the graph. I really appreciate youre help @RossMillikan. Now looking at the graph, because I am unable to zoom, can you just give me a quick synopsis of how I'd determine the minimum from the graph? I see it would be at the lowest point, but how was x=40-(20/sqrt3) found?

Comment: I don't know how you would find an exact solution from the graph. You can zoom in as much as you want and find more and more decimal places by eye, but you won't find the exact answer this way.  Taking the derivative (which gets the slope of the tangent to the curve) and setting to zero gets an equation you can solve to get that answer.  If you don't have that tool available (and you shouldn't in precalc) a numerical approximation seems to me the best you can do.

Comment: To determine how much of the old road should be constructed, I would take the estimated minimum value and multiply it by the cost of reconstruction, correct? 200000*(40-20/sqrt3)?

Comment: I think i figured it out. I don't have to factor the minimum value into the cost function because the minimum of x would equal the distance from A-C correct?

Comment: No, the amount of the old road to be reconstructed is the minimum, so according to you is 25.3 miles.  When I look at the graph it is closer to 28.4 miles.  You could plug this into your formula to get the total cost.  $40-20/\sqrt 3 \approx 28.45$

Comment: Thank you! I noticed I forgot to square the x in the radical. Now that I've corrected it I see the minimum to be about 28.4. Thank you for all of your help.